# How to find the index of an element in symbolic matrix based on a symbol?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy

I would like to find the index of a value in symbolic matrix. For example, i want to find the index which have 'Zc' symbol in the below Q matrix.

```
from sympy import symbols, Matrix
Zc,Yc,L=symbols("Zc Yc L",real=True)
Q=Matrix(([0,Zc,-Y],[-Zc*L,0,L/2],[Yc,-L/2,0]))
```

expected answer is [(0,1),(1,0)].

I tried with numpy.where but it returned an empty set.That is,

```
numpy.where(A in K_P.free_symbols)
```

It gave an empty set as,
    (array([0], dtype=int64)

**Part 2:**
If the Q matrix is

```
Q=Matrix(([0,Zc*L/6,-Yc],[-L*Zc/12,0,L/2],[Yc,-L*Zc*Yc/2,0]))
```

If i would like to find the index based on a product of symbols,i.e., `Zc*L`. Then how should i proceed. It should give me index if the value is `Zc*L` and `L*Zc`. But not the index of `-L*Zc*Yc/2`. So expected answer is `[(0,1),(1,0)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a NumPy-style operation, it's not particularly mathematical or Matrix-like. To use NumPy methods, first convert Q to a NumPy array first, and then search through the array, applying `lambda expr: Zc in expr.free_symbols`. Putting everything together,

```
idx = np.nonzero(np.vectorize(lambda expr: Zc in expr.free_symbols)(np.array(Q)))
```

returns `(array([0, 1]), array([1, 0]))`

Caution: this is not a tuple of row-column coordinates, this is a tuple [row coordinates], [column coordinates]. For example, if there was also Zc in bottom right cornet, then idx is

```
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([1, 0, 2]))
```

A more readable form, and the one you probably want, is obtained with `np.array(idx).T`:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 2]])
```

---

Or, without NumPy, just loop over the elements and report what you found.

```
found = []
for i in range(2):
  for j in range(2):
    if Zc in Q[i, j].free_symbols:
      found.append([i, j])
print(found)
```

Here is a modification of this loop where we search for an expression, such as the product of two symbols. The test is whether the expression is modified if that product is replaced by 0. Also, apparently you don't want other symbols present? Check for that is added too.

```
found = []
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    if Q[i, j].subs(Zc*L, 0) != Q[i, j] and Q[i, j].free_symbols == set([L, Zc]):
      found.append([i, j])
print(found)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question on the similar line. If i need to find  the index based on a product of symbol like, Zc*L. Then how should i proceed. I have edited my question to include this question as part 2 and detailed description is given above.

Comment: In the second answer you have provided, if the 'for loop' range is 3 then it gives the index of all product symbols, Zc*L. So this code gives, [[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 1]]. But the [2, 1] element is -L*Zc*Yc/2. I do not want this to be included into the index array. I want only the index of the product between Zc and L (not L*Zc*Yc) . How i can do this?

Comment: The requirements are getting increasingly vague, but I added a version for that.

Comment: That works. Thank you. one more help. If i want to call an element in matrix Q based on the index saved in array 'found', how can i do this operation? I tried using Q[found[0,0]]. but ended in an error "type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple".

Comment: I have converted list 'found' to array using np.asarray(found). then i am able to retrieve the Q matrix values using the index in found array, found_ar=np.asarray(found)
print("Q element",Q[found_ar[0,0],found_ar[0,1]]). Thank again Ivan for your help. You made my day.